# Angular proxy all without one

Tags: angular, proxy

I have application with this `proxy.conf.json`:

```
{
    "*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8081",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Now if I want endpoints that have `base` in its path to `targt` `localhost` port `8082` how can I do that?

I checked:

```
{
    "*base*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8082",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug"
    },
    "*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8081",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

But I don't think that it works that way.

To clarify:
I would like two rules, one for `base` and second for all but not I want rules to catch

1. for example `/api`  (or `/base` or whatever)
2. all without for example `/api` (or `/base` or whatever)

I wanted to do it with two rules in one config.

Answer (score 0):

For me i use this
proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api" : "" }
  }
}
```

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json ",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

After in my servics for exemple I can do

```
this.httclient.post("api/users")
```

Comment: This does not answer my question how to do `proxy.conf.json` that has "all" requests but "/api" request in one config ?

Comment: By replacing /api by *

Comment: yes, but i would like two rules, one for `/api` and second for all but not `/api` - you only proposing one rule which is not enough. `*` will catch `all`, `/api` will catch `/api`. Please propose rules to catch 1. `/api` and 2. all without `/api` with two rules in `one` config.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follow:

```
{
    "/base/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8092",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug"
    },
    "*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8081",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I missmatched `port` in `question` but that approach was ok.

I was getting `504 HTTP error`.

The order is important.
The `*` must be `second` rule.